# Console ASCII Decision Tree to Dash Plotly dashboard

Tags: python, html, markdown, ascii, plotly-dash

I have an ASCII representation of a decision tree output to the console:
[image]
However, in Dash Plotly, this renders as:
[image: ![image|690x175](upload://vIpF984J8ZrR9M6ILD8u3ANdh1n.png)]

In Notepad++ with all characters being displayed this looks like:
[image: ![image|690x235](upload://gCC2uAYdhGzhZOxB4w0FDgv9rON.png)]

Is there a way to get Dash to properly display this ASCII decision tree? I've tried output to HTML.H# as well straight to a Div. I've also tried dcc.Markdown. So far, the tree is just being completely garbled?

EDIT: I was able to find a solution. Using Dash Plotly's html.Pre() (https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/pre), I was able to successfully display the tree. In addition, in order to change to a monospace font as mentioned in the comment below, I used the style argument inside html.Pre():

```
html.Pre(id='tree',style={'font-family':'courier'})
```

Comment: You are getting a garbled output probably because it is not a monospace font. If it's possible to change the font to any monospace font, give that a try...